# How can Rubymotion create bridge metadata on Leopard ?

Tags: rubymotion, sparrow-framework

I am using 1.8.24 of gems and 1.9 of rubymotion on Snow Leopard and trying to compile the
SparrowInMotion sample project.

I added require 'rubygems' to the Rakefile but it is still crashing on the "invalid option: --no-64-bit" of gen_bridge_data. I thought this bug was fixed ?

invalid option: --no-64-bit
Usage: gen_bridge_metadata [options] 
Use the `-h' flag or consult gen_bridge_metadata(1) for help.
    ERROR! Error when generating bridge metadata: /usr/bin/gen_bridge_metadata --format complete --no-64-bit --cflags "-isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -D__ENVIRONMENT_IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__=50000 -I. -I"/Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework"" /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPALSound.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPALSoundChannel.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPAnimatable.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/Sparrow.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPAudioEngine.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPAVSound.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPAVSoundChannel.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPBitmapChar.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPBitmapFont.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPButton.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPCompiledSprite.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPDelayedInvocation.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPDisplayObject.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPDisplayObject_Internal.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPDisplayObjectContainer.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPEnterFrameEvent.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPEvent.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPEvent_Internal.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPEventDispatcher.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPGLTexture.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPImage.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPJuggler.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPMacros.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPMatrix.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPMovieClip.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPNSExtensions.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPPoint.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPPoolObject.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPQuad.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPRectangle.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPRenderSupport.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPRenderTexture.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPSound.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPSoundChannel.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPSprite.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPStage.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPStage_Internal.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPSubTexture.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTextField.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTexture.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTextureAtlas.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTouch.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTouch_Internal.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTouchEvent.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTouchProcessor.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTransitions.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTween.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPTweenedProperty.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPUtils.h /Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Headers/Sparrow-Framework/SPView.h -o "/Volumes/osx big/jon/projects/SparrowInMotion/vendor/Pods/Pods.bridgesupport"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was because I didn't have Bridge Support installed. Hit up the [MacRuby files directory, download and install BridgeSupport Preview 3.zip](http://macruby.macosforge.org/files/).

I figured that out by following the instructions on [Setting up MacRuby for OS X Snow Leopard](https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Setting-up-MacRuby)

Comment: @angelofcode if I'm not mistaken, I believe it got patched in the latest version of RubyMotion.